# How can I step by step save my progress with Javascript? (in a Browser)

Tags: javascript, browser, save, progress

I've wrote a programm for the console of my browser.

If it's done it returns a result, that I want to save in some way. Afterwards I need to progress some steps in browser manually (the programm isn't running anymore). And the programm runs again and again return a result.

Is there some way to store the combined result?

At the end I always want to return something like:

```
return storedResults + currentResult;
```

Comment: So why not make storedResults a global variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store result of your console applications you can use the Web Storage API.

> The Web Storage API provides mechanisms by which browsers can securely
>   store key/value pairs, in a much more intuitive fashion than using
>   cookies.

Save result (three different way to do It):

```
localStorage.result = 'OK';
localStorage['result'] = 'OK';
localStorage.setItem('result', 'OK');
```

View result:

```
console.log(localStorage.result); // print "OK"
```

See complete [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know about this one. It is exactly what I am looking for. :)